# Insert identity column value into table from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table #test (a int identity(1,1), b varchar(20), c varchar(20))

insert into #test (b,c) values ('bvju','hjab')
insert into #test (b,c) values ('bst','sdfkg')
......
insert into #test (b,c) values ('hdsj','kfsd')
```

How would I insert the identity value (`#test.a`) that got populated from the above insert statements into `#sample` table (another table)

```
create table #sample (d int identity(1,1), e int, f varchar(20))

insert into #sample(e,f) values (identity value from #test table, 'jkhjk')
insert into #sample(e,f) values (identity value from #test table, 'hfhfd')
......
insert into #sample(e,f) values (identity value from #test table, 'khyy')
```

Could any one please explain how I could implement this for larger set of records (thousands of records)?

Can we use `while` loop and `scope_identity`? If so, please explain how can we do it?

what would be the scenario if i insert into #test from a select query?

insert into #test (b,c) 
select ... from ... (thousands of records)

How would i capture the identity value and use that value into another (#sample) 
insert into #sample(e,f) 
select (identity value from #test), ... from .... (thousand of records) –

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the question in your deleted comment.

Comment: "Can we use while loop and scope_identity? "  PLEASE CONSIDER SET BASED.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`output`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause. From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The OUTPUT clause returns information from, or expressions based on, each row affected
>   by an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. These results can be
>   returned to the processing application for use in such things as
>   confirmation messages, archiving, and other such application
>   requirements. **The results can also be inserted into a table or table
>   variable.** Additionally, you can capture the results of an OUTPUT
>   clause in a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement, and
>   insert those results into a target table or view.

like so:

```
create table #tempids (a int) -- a temp table for holding our identity values

insert into #test 
(b,c) 
output inserted.a into #tempids -- put the inserted identity value into #tempids
values 
('bvju','hjab')
```

You then asked...

> What if the insert is from a select instead?

It works the same way...

```
insert into #test 
(b,c) 
output inserted.a into #tempids -- put the inserted identity value into #tempids
select -- except you use a select here
 Column1
,Column2
from SomeSource
```

It works the same way whether you insert from values, a derived table, an execute statement, a dml table source, or default values. **If you insert 1000 records, you'll get 1000 ids in `#tempids`.**

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote up a "set based" sample with the output clause.

Here it is.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationPersonParentTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationPersonParentTable
end



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable
end



CREATE TABLE #DestinationPersonParentTable
(
PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKey int not null identity (1001, 1), 
SSNNaturalKey int, 
HireDate datetime
)



declare @PersonOutputResultsAuditTable table
(
SSNNaturalKey int, 
PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyAudit int
)





CREATE TABLE #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable
(
DestinationChildSurrogateIdentityKey int not null identity (3001, 1), 
PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK int, 
EmailAddressValueNaturalKey varchar(64),
EmailAddressType int
)





-- Declare XML variable

DECLARE @data XML;

-- Element-centered XML

SET @data = N'
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Person>
        <SSN>222222222</SSN>
        <HireDate>2002-02-02</HireDate>
    </Person>

    <Person>
        <SSN>333333333</SSN>
        <HireDate>2003-03-03</HireDate>
    </Person>

    <EmailAddress>
        <SSNLink>222222222</SSNLink>
        <EmailAddressValue>g@g.com</EmailAddressValue>
        <EmailAddressType>1</EmailAddressType>
    </EmailAddress>

    <EmailAddress>
        <SSNLink>222222222</SSNLink>
        <EmailAddressValue>h@h.com</EmailAddressValue>
        <EmailAddressType>2</EmailAddressType>
    </EmailAddress>

    <EmailAddress>
        <SSNLink>333333333</SSNLink>
        <EmailAddressValue>a@a.com</EmailAddressValue>
        <EmailAddressType>1</EmailAddressType>
    </EmailAddress>

    <EmailAddress>
        <SSNLink>333333333</SSNLink>
        <EmailAddressValue>b@b.com</EmailAddressValue>
        <EmailAddressType>2</EmailAddressType>
    </EmailAddress>

</root>

';




INSERT INTO #DestinationPersonParentTable ( SSNNaturalKey ,  HireDate )

output inserted.SSNNaturalKey , inserted.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKey  into @PersonOutputResultsAuditTable ( SSNNaturalKey , PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyAudit)

SELECT T.parentEntity.value('(SSN)[1]', 'INT') AS SSN,
       T.parentEntity.value('(HireDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS HireDate
FROM @data.nodes('root/Person') AS T(parentEntity)
/* add a where not exists check on the natural key */
where not exists (
    select null from #DestinationPersonParentTable innerRealTable where innerRealTable.SSNNaturalKey = T.parentEntity.value('(SSN)[1]', 'INT') )
;

/* Optional.  You could do a UPDATE here based on matching the #DestinationPersonParentTableSSNNaturalKey = T.parentEntity.value('(SSN)[1]', 'INT')
You could Combine INSERT and UPDATE using the MERGE function on 2008 or later.
 */


select 'PersonOutputResultsAuditTable_Results' as Label, * from @PersonOutputResultsAuditTable


INSERT INTO #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable (  PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK ,  EmailAddressValueNaturalKey , EmailAddressType )
SELECT  par.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyAudit , 
        T.childEntity.value('(EmailAddressValue)[1]', 'varchar(64)') AS EmailAddressValue,
        T.childEntity.value('(EmailAddressType)[1]', 'INT') AS EmailAddressType
FROM @data.nodes('root/EmailAddress') AS T(childEntity)
/* The next join is the "trick".  Join on the natural key (SSN)....**BUT** insert the PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKey into the table */
join @PersonOutputResultsAuditTable par on par.SSNNaturalKey = T.childEntity.value('(SSNLink)[1]', 'INT')
where not exists (
    select null from #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable innerRealTable where innerRealTable.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK = par.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyAudit AND  innerRealTable.EmailAddressValueNaturalKey = T.childEntity.value('(EmailAddressValue)[1]', 'varchar(64)'))
;



print '/#DestinationPersonParentTable/'
select * from #DestinationPersonParentTable


print '/#DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable/'
select * from #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable


select SSNNaturalKey , HireDate , '---' as Sep1 , EmailAddressValueNaturalKey , EmailAddressType , '---' as Sep2, par.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKey as ParentPK , child.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK as childFK from #DestinationPersonParentTable par join #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable child
on par.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKey = child.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationPersonParentTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationPersonParentTable
end


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into #test (b,c) values ('bvju','hjab')
insert into #sample(e,f) values (@SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'jkhjk')
```

@SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns the last identity value used

Comment: using @SCOPE_IDENTITY() it returns the last identity value, but how to capture all the identity records from #test table?

Comment: You would need to use a cursor to do one at a time so you can insert table A then insert table B that same ID.  canon's method is better though, as it is a set based operation and will be more efficient.